# Convert from XML in format A to XML in format B

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

The schema for the XML file is changing and i need to create a utility that will take the xml file in format A and convert it to format B. How can i do it.

I am not able to figure out the starting point for it.

Comment: With **XSLT**, a .xsl in XML format too that with template matching transforms one XML to text or XML. Download a cheat sheet and start simple. Study some samples.

Comment: There are a lot of XML parsers in java . Did you try to google it?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to look into XSLT. You can write one for each iteration of changes, which hopefully you, or whoever is changing the XML, is versioning each change. If that is the case, you will easily be able to transform each version into the next.

On the chance that you do not have versions available to you for the XML, then you will probably have to do very strict matching on your XSLTs.